# Rails: access related field data in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Excuse me for the seemingly basic question, but I'm new to Rails and I can't seem to google anything useful.

I have two models: `Works has_many Pictures`.

Both models have a `:title`.

If, in my `works/index.html.erb` file, I include:

> `<%= work.title %>`

The title of the `Work` shows up as expected.

Likewise, if I include:

> `<%= work.pictures[0] %>`

The class id of the first related record from `Pictures` shows up, because (I believe) they are correctly linked via `has_many` and `belongs_to`.

But if I do this instead:

> `<%= work.pictures[0].title %>`

I get a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'title' for nil:NilClass`

I know the `Pictures` model has a title field.  Obviously I'm not doing it right; what am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `class id of the first related record from Pictures shows up`. Do you mean that when `work.pictures[0]` returns a record or an id?

Comment: Also, the error suggests that `work.pictures[0]` is nil. Does `work.pictures` return an array of pictures?

Comment: aaargh, I figured it out... I'm manually relating the two tables, just to get started, and with each new migration, Rails changed my record IDs.  Rake db:reset fixed everything.  Thanks for putting me in the right direction at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with inaccurate record ids...

> `Works.pictures[0].title`

...does indeed work.